# Left alignment in lists

Tags: lists, enumerate

The result of the following code snippet is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item {\raggedleft  \textbf {Inference Rules}}\\
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item First Item
        \end{enumerate}
        {\raggedleft \textbf {Logic}}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can anyone help me align with the word "Logic" on the left below number 1?

Comment: No need for the `raggedleft`.

Comment: Without this command, "Logic" is below "Inference Rules, not 1.

Comment: @gmn_1450: Why not put `Logic` *outside* the `enumerate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple with `enumitem`: use the `wide`option`, like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[wide, leftmargin=\parindent]
        \item \textbf {Inference Rules}\\
        \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=2\parindent]
            \item First Item
        \end{enumerate}
         \textbf {Logic}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you explain to me what the command does?

Comment: `wide` makes the label left-aligned, with a default indent of `\parindent`, and the item contents is aligned with the label (for instance, if you set `wide=0pt`, the label and the item content are aligned on the left margin